# QML connect signal from the main component to the child components

Tags: qml, connect, signal-handling

I have a Qt application that calls `qt_update_values()` to the main QML component. I want to send the new values to a specific delegate. How do I connect `update_values()` from the main component to be received by a specific child component, which is defined in another qml?

I have tried defining Connections in the child, but I am not sure what target I need to define...

In the `main.qml` i have something similar to this:

```
...
signal update_values(new_values)

function qt_update_values(newValues){
     update_values(newValues);
}

Repeater {
     id:idRepeater
     model: 3

     Rectangle {
         id:example

         Text{ text: "hello"}
         ...

         AnotherComponent {name: "name", othervariables: "others"}
     }
}
...
```

Then on `AnotherComponent.qml` i have:

```
...
signal update_values_child(new_values)

function onUpdate_values(newValues){
     textid = newValues;
}

Text{ id:textid}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't connect from the parent to the main, but the other way around like this:

```
...
id: idOfTheParent  // <=== THIS IS IMPORTANT
signal update_values(new_values)

function qt_update_values(newValues){
     update_values(newValues);
}

Repeater {
    id:idRepeater
    model: 3

    Rectangle {
        id:example

        Text{ text: "hello"}
        ...

        AnotherComponent {
            id: idOfAnotherComponent // This ID is only available in the 
                                     // scope of the Component
                                     // that will be instantiated by the
                                     // Repeater, i.e. children of the Rectangle
            name: "name"
            othervariables: "others"
        }
        Connections {
            target: idOfTheParent
            onUpdate_values: idOfAnotherComponent.dosomethingWith(new_values)
        }
    }
}
...
```

You could also use `signal.connect()` to add new connections

```
Repeater {
    model: 10
    delegate: Item { ... }
    onItemAdded: {
        idOfTheParent.update_values.connect(function() { // do what you want })
    }
}
```

But if it is only broadcasting of a new value, the *declarative* way would be, to have properties in your delegate, and bind them to the properties that held the changeing values:

```
...
id: idOfTheParent
property var valueThatWillChange

Repeater {
    model: 10
    delegate: Item {
        property int valueThatShallChangeToo: idOfTheParent.valueThatWillChange
    }
}
...
```

---

To have all of it with different signals ofc. is possible:

For the `Connections`-solution the simplest thing is to call `doSomething` only if it is the right delegate instance:

```
// in the delegate
Connections {
    target: idOfTheParent
    onValue1Updated: if (index === 1) doYourStuff()
    onValue2Updated: if (index === 2) doYourStuff()
    onValue...
}
```

But this is easier with the second method:

```
id: idOfTheParent
Repeater {
    model: 10
    delegate: SomeItem {
        function doSomething() { console.log(index, 'does something')
    }
    onItemAdded: {
        idOfTheParent['value' + index + 'Updated'].connect(item.doSomething)
    }
    onItemRemoved: {
        idOfTheParent['value' + index + 'Updated'].disconnect(item.doSomething)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks you @derM. It actually does more than just update... I was trying the first method, and I get no errors, but I have set a console.log on dosomethingWith(new_values) in the delegate, and it does not show anything at all. It seems as if the function is not being called...

Comment: sorry my mistake, I forgot to add the parameters at the end. It works! Thank you!!! @derM

Comment: one last question,is there any way to connect only specific delegates and not all of them (in my example, delegates will be a series of charts which will be dynamic). I want to connect each chart with a different qt_update_value_chart1 or qt_update_value_chart2... Is it possible? @derM